# Retrieve tags by id defined within a conditional template in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, templates, polymer

Context:

I am working with polymer (0.2.2) on Maverics MacOX (10.9.2) & Chrome agent (34.0.1847.131) building up web components with conditional templates.

Problem:

I am including a tag with an id within a conditional template. When I try to retrieve this tag as a JS node by means of the `this.$` object, an `undefined` value is returned although the condition evaluates to true. Herein there is a snippet of sample code:

On HTML template:

```
...
<template if="{{true-condition}}">
  <wc-my-tag id="A"></wc-my-tag>
</template>
...
```

On Script:

```
Polymer ('wc-my-tag', {
   ...
   ready: function () {
       console.log (this.$.A); // prints "undefined" ???
   }
}
```

Question:

It looks like the `this.$` object were filled in before the template resolution. Is this a bug within the polymer library or a normal behavior? Anyway, how could I proceed to get the tag under id="A" in the snippet?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, conditional templates aren't written into the DOM until their conditions return true. Double check that {{true-condition}} actually is true at the time that ready is called. If it is, consider putting your handler in domReady instead. If that doesn't work, try using `this.async` to delay until after Polymer has had a chance to do the last bit of evaluation and rendering, e.g.: `this.async(function() {console.log(this.$.A);}.bind(this));`

If all of that doesn't work, post a jsfiddle of the code so we can debug it :)

I'd also strongly encourage you to grab the latest version of Polymer, 0.2.4. It's such a rapidly moving project right now that it pays to stick to the latest version when possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter, your answer was very useful for me. The lessons learned from here are: 1) code building the model of web components should be filled up to enable templates to be resolved asap whilst 2) code evaluation revolving around the use of `this.$` within the context of templates should be conveniently delayed by means of `this.async` or placing them in the proper lifecycle method.

Nevertheless, I have a very close issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727825). It would be very nice if you could have a look at it.

Comment: Btw, do you know any resource to get always the last version of polymer platform in order to avoid continuous updates?

Comment: You could fetch the files from a CDN if that works for you: http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#is-the-code-hosted-on-a-cdn

Comment: Thanks Peter, indeed we were already fetching the libraries from the CDN but it is necessary to explicitly include the version number in the URI. What I asked for was about a reference pointing permanently at the latest version of polymer. I have a lot of `index.html` to change each time :P