# Accessing the light DOM included by means of a content tag in Polymer

Tags: javascript, templates, polymer

Context:

I am working with polymer (0.2.4) on Maverics MacOX (10.9.2) & Chrome agent (34.0.1847.131) building up web components. Particularly, I am trying to partially enrich two components (`foo` and `bar`) included in other template by means of a `content` tag. The enrichment consists of adding new attributes for using them within their respective inner templates (lines (3) and (4)). I am not sure whether this approach will work properly which is what I need. But it gets me to the following problem.

Problem:

I am trying to access from JS the `light-DOM` nodes included in a template by a content tag. Essentially my intention can be depicted in the following snippet. I need to access nodes `foo` and `bar` in lines (1) and (2):

```
<polymer-element name="wc-tag"> 
  <template>
     <div id="container">
       <content select="[role='rA']"></content>  
       <content select="[role='rB']"></content>  
     </div>
  </template>
  <script>
     Polymer ('wc-tag',{
        domReady: function () {
           var c  = this.$.container;
           var rA = c.querySelector ('[role="rA"]'); // (1)
           var rB = c.querySelector ('[role="rB"]'); // (2)
           rA.setAttribute ('mode', 'active'); // (3)
           rB.setAttribute ('editable', true); // (4)
           ...
        }
     });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

 <wc-tag>
    <wc-foo role="rA">Foo</wc-foo>
    <wc-bar role="rB">Bar</wc-bar>
 </wc-tag>
```

Nevertheless, a null value is obtained in both `rA` and `rB`. I have confirmed that when code is evaluated, the `content` tags have not been resolved yet (`content` are the two only children with `<div id="container">`).

Question:

Does anybody knows how/when could/should I access `foo` and `bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky, I haven't done this with Polymer yet so there's a bit of speculation here. Let me know if this works (and post a jsbin if it doesn't :)

Here's my understanding. In the shadow dom, the `<content>` nodes don't exactly have the `<wc-foo/bar>` elements as children. Those are still part of the light dom, they're just effectively copied over. So because you're querying for children of `this.$.container` in the shadow dom for elements with `role="rA"` you won't find them because they're in the light dom. Two options: you could give the `<content>` nodes identifying attributes so you can select them and then call [getDistributedElements()](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#accessContentDOM) on them; or you could do `this.querySelector` rather than `this.$.container.querySelector`.

Related reading: [How to style distributed nodes](http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html#style-distributed)

Comment: Thanks Peter, feel yourself included in the comment I posted for Rob ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/lawaf/6/edit) of how to do this using `<content>` elements and the getDistributedNodes method.

```
<polymer-element name="x-foo">
  <template>
    <h1>Hello from x-foo</h1>
    <content id="content" select='[role="rA"]'></content>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('x-foo', {
      domReady: function() {
        var baz = this.$.content.getDistributedNodes()[0];
        baz.setAttribute('active', true);
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<x-foo>
  <div role="rA">rA element</div>
</x-foo>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob for your answer. It is exactly what I was looking for ;). I hope some day to get the broad knowledge about the hidden and slippery shadow DOM API that you and Peter show ;).